# Is there a way to have a selected disabled option in select tag in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to react, generally in HTML we would do `<option selected disabled>Choose an option</option>`
But the selected attribute doesn't seem to work with option tag in react for me.
Here is the code snippet:

```
<select name="status" value={status} onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} required>
            <option value="0">* Select Professional Status</option>
            <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
            <option value="Junior Developer">Junior Developer</option>
            <option value="Senior Developer">Senior Developer</option>
            <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
            <option value="Student or Learning">Student or Learning</option>
            <option value="Instructor">Instructor or Teacher</option>
            <option value="Intern">Intern</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select>
```

I basically want to put a label for the dropdown, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [React-select](https://react-select.com/home#getting-started) for that and add placeholder.

```
<Select options={options} placeholder="..."/>
```

Comment: Didn't know about this, does exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if that answer helped you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

actually, to target elements in select element in react you should have to try e.target.value instead of only e.